# Separating date and time from a Tweet in CouchDB

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb, tweets

I'm new using CouchDB harvesting tweets. I'm working with map function to create a view, trying to separate date and hour from `doc.created_at` of a JSON object by using JavaScript.

This is my code:

```
function(doc) {
  var d= new Date(doc.created_at);
  emit(doc._id,d.getTime());
}
```

The problem is that the time is not user readable. When I use parse, it does not return any value.

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: What "time" is not user readable? `getTime` returns milliseconds since 1970/01/01.

Comment: For example if I have in created_at: "Thu Sep 19 13:30:42 +0000 2013" getTime() returns 1379597442000 instead of 13:30:42

Comment: As I said, it returns milliseconds. Look at the documentation for the JavaScript Date object.

Comment: It would help if you expressed the format you would like to see being output. But a good start to look things up would be: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I used toLocaleDateString() and toLocaleTimeString() to separate the doc.created_at, then I grouped them with the reduce function and it worked.